# Binding NextJS to ASP.NET Core 6 React.js project

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, next.js

I have created an ASP.NET Core React.js project template in Visual Studio and I am currently trying to bind NextJS to it.

I have deleted the existing `ClientApp` folder and created a new one using `npx create-next-app@latest` to a new folder client-app.

In my `.csproj` file, I have changed the SpaRoot to

```
<SpaRoot>client-app\</SpaRoot>
```

However, when I run the application, it fails to start due to this:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0] Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'

Maybe there is something that I have to configure additionally in the `Program.cs` or the `.csproj` file?

I couldn't find any information on this and I'm completely new to react stuff, so I hope someone can help me out. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Could you show more details of the error message? and the Scripts node in your package.json?

Comment: here's  a issue may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942659/npm-install-succeeds-but-npm-run-start-fails-to-find-both-rimraf-and-react-scrip